# Remove all the word before a specific word

Tags: php

I have this URL and I want to remove all characters before "**blog_images/**" this world.

```
http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg
```

I have tried this PHP function it removes all words but I want to remove this word also, I need to get only this characters **woman4.jpg**

```
strstr(http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg, 'blog_images/');
```

Comment: Use [`basename`](https://eval.in/1026885)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use explode like this,

$dat = explode('blog_images/','http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg');

echo $dat[1];

Comment: `basename` is more better : `echo basename('http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg');`

Comment: yes, its an alternative

Comment: No your suggestion will not work in other case, like if url change. so your answer is not alternative of `basename()`, But this could be [alternative](https://eval.in/1026889)

Answer (score 1):

You can get file name using **basename** function **php**

```
<?php
/* $your_file_path_along_with_file_name is your input path */
$your_file_path_along_with_file_name = "http://localhost/login/uploads/blog_images/woman4.jpg";
$original_file_name = basename($your_file_path_along_with_file_name);
echo $original_file_name //it prints your file name
?>
```